# Blender Game Engine, python inserting a cube at coordinates

Tags: python, objects

First of all I am a BIG noob at blender but not at python. I want to maker some python games so I thought that blender would be great for this.

I am half way through making my simple game where you move a block around and now I want to make it so when you press the E key, a block appears in front of the cube.

Here is my code so far which I found on-line:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.add(type='MESH')
ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data


me.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
me.update()
```

It inserts a mesh at some random coordinates. Does anyonee know how to make it insert a cube at some set coordinates or just simplify my code?

I apologise if my terminology isn't correct but I am new to all of this.

Comment: Oh sorry guys I entered the code wrongly.

Comment: Here is the code:

Comment: import bpy

bpy.ops.object.add(type='MESH')
ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data


me.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
me.update()

Comment: Welcome !,  `bpy` is used in blender but not in the game engine which has kind of separate API which uses `bge`

Comment: see this answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26656/how-to-add-an-object-at-a-specific-posistion-in-blender-game-engine/27695#27695

Comment: if you still having problems edit your question to address the issue