# add object at specific location with python?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

This might be a really stupid question-I'm working in bpy right now and want to add a plane at a specific location...I know that [How to add an object at a specific posistion in Blender Game Engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26656/how-to-add-an-object-at-a-specific-posistion-in-blender-game-engine) works for bge but am not sure if it'll work in bpy...

Answer (score 4):

The tooltip of the *Add > Mesh > Plane* menu path shows this information, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it to clipboard.

#### Tooltip

[image]

All of these menu items trigger *operators* and take several optional arguments, `location=(x,y,z)` included. The same applies to the other items in the Curve, Surface Metaball etc., menus.

#### Docs

The total list can be found in several locations, [in the docs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_3/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add)

#### Blender's Python Console

use the auto complete feature (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>) in the Blender python console after typing `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_`

[image]

The arguments to the `bpy.ops.*` can be found doing auto completion too

[image]

#### Info Panel

You can see the history of most of the code which has been triggered in the UI, in the Info panel if you drag it down

[image]

Comment: "CTRL-C on a ToolTip" to copy the datapath or the Python function is a great TIP..works with SHIFT-CTRL-C on fields with values and checkboxes in all other windows

Answer (score 0):

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(location=(x,y,z))
```

does the trick

Comment: will you please add more to this answer, to make it more useful for future viewers.