# Creating blender objects with matrix of 3D coordinates?

Tags: objects, matrix

I have a matrix of 3D coordinates for about 10,000 points. Is there a way to import this matrix into blender in such a way that it creates a simple sphere of the same size at each point in the matrix or can anyone point me in the right direction of some documentation on how to do this?

Example:

[1,]-2.0256547 -3.0332452 -1.596550 -1.662259 -1.633215
[2,]  2.4796049 2.4291108  3.102889  3.030494  3.049240
[3,]  0.5200771  0.8193005 -1.868664 -1.890152 -1.896593

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to use simple python scripting to achieve this. See questions such as https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34946/add-object-at-specific-location-with-python for more info.

Comment: Thanks, ill check that out!