# How to add copy of an object from a controller without Logic Brick being present?

Tags: python, objects

I mean without controller being connected to `Edit Object > Add Object` Brick. Furthermore, I need to add that object at a specific location, instead of putting it on top of the owner, since I will be adding more than one object so they can't be all at one location. I tried moving the owner but it cannot move and create objects more than once in a single frame for some reason, probably because it takes a frame to pass for a controller to reach a signal towards an actuator Brick. So I figured doing it from a controller might be a solution but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to add an object at a specific posistion in Blender Game Engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26656/how-to-add-an-object-at-a-specific-posistion-in-blender-game-engine)

```
import bge

scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
object = scene.addObject("Sphere","Sphere")
object.worldPosition = [1,1,1]
```